# Highlighting a selected Dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe and two lists where one list consists of colors and another consists of targets. I want to check if data in column C is in targets and if it does, I want the entire row highlighted.

I wrote the code below

```
colour = ["red","blue","yellow"]
targets = ["talk","cry","laugh"]

view = pd.DataFrame({
         'B':[1,2,3,4,5],
         'C':["love","laff","laugh","talk","talk"]
       })


def higlight_Cell(x):
    count=0
    for column in view:
        for i in targets:
            if i in view[column]:
                return ['background-color: {}'.format(color[i])]
                count+=1

view.style.apply(higlight_Cell, axis=0)
```

When running the code, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Function <function higlight_Cell at 0x000001E16AF0B168> returned the wrong shape.
Result has shape: (2,)
Expected shape:   (5, 2)
Out[41]: <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler at 0x1e16d587508>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format the whole row, then `x` is a row, so you want to access the `C` indexed. Also, since `x` is a row, you want to return a format array with the same length as `x` (which is what the error complains)

```
def highlight(x):
    for c,t in zip(colour, targets):
        # check for 'C' value
        if x.loc['C']==t: 
            return [f'background-color: {c}']*len(x)

        # if you want to check for any value, replace the above with
        # if x.eq(t).any(): return [f'background-color: {c}']*len(x)

    return ['']*len(x)

view.style.apply(highlight, axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks but  i couldnt view the output. this messaged was displayed on my console <pandas.io.formats.style.Styler at 0x1e16d58c388>